# How to change dropdown and textbox values using javascript

Tags: javascript, salesforcedx, dom

My salesforce page has dropdown and textbox, but require a double click to enter

[image: dropdown]

[image: textbox]

Here is DOM for Ground snow load
[image]
my thought was to change the value of dropdown by id
document.getElementById('00NE0000000eRDx').value = "107";
but this does not work

I need the value of the dropdown and the text box to be changed with my variable in javascript and i need them saved (i could click save in a seperate step)
My thought was to use sfdcPage.getInlineEditData("00NE0000000eRDx").openField or something like that since document.getElementById did not work

using the Salesforce Classic UI where I can input using browser automation.
I was hoping to use the console and input javascript to change the value of the textbox or to change the dropdown value/text chosen. Im not sure i understand the use apex:actionFunction. would you be able to suggest more clearly how to use this?

Comment: Are you building a Visualforce page? This looks like standard Salesforce Classic UI; are you working on something like browser automation? Could you make an [edit] to flesh out your use case?

Comment: We would need to see some code to give you a direct code answer.

Answer (score 0):

With inline editing, that's how it works. If you want to change the value while you're not inline editing, use [apex:actionFunction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) to set the new value in the View State, and the page will update accordingly.

Comment: please see edits. i think you are on the right track but i need it all to be able to work from console. i am simply taking data from somewhere else and want to input into sf